# C# minimax algorithm implementation returning values such as -1000, -3000, -8000, etc

Tags: c#, minimax

I am trying to implement minimax in my C# code for tictactoe.  For some reason, when the depth = 1 and I debug it to check to see all of the values returned from different paths; I see crazy values like -1000, -5000, -1000, etc! How is this possible? What is happening?  This is my full code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Minimax_TicTacToe
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        //Definition constants
        private const int EMPTY = 0;
        private const int PLAYER = 1;
        private const int COMPUTER = 2;
        private const int PLAYER_WON = 0;
        private const int COMPUTER_WON = 1;
        private const int DRAW = 2;
        private const int GAME = 3;
        private const int OVER = 4;

        //Internals
        private int turns = 0;
        private int turn = PLAYER;
        private String player_mark = "X";
        private String computer_mark = "O";

        //Grid
        private byte[] grid = { 
                                  0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0
                              };

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        /*
        private int Minimax(byte[] ngrid, int depth = 0, int score = 0)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
            {
                return Minimax(new byte[] { grid[0], grid[1], grid[2], 
                                            grid[3], grid[4], grid[5], 
                                            grid[6], grid[7], grid[8] },
                                            depth + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                int status = GameStatus(ngrid);
                if (status == PLAYER_WON) return -1;
                else if (status == COMPUTER_WON) return 1;
                else if (status == DRAW) return 0;
                int i;

                for (i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ngrid[i] == 0)
                    {
                        byte[] board = new byte[] { 
                            ngrid[0], ngrid[1], ngrid[2], 
                            ngrid[3], ngrid[4], ngrid[5], 
                            ngrid[6], ngrid[7], ngrid[8]
                        };

                        board[i] = (depth % 2 == 0) ? (byte)PLAYER : (byte)COMPUTER;
                        score = Minimax(board, depth + 1);
                        if (score == 1 && depth == 1) return i;
                        if (score == 1) return 1;

                    }
                }

                return 0;

            }


        }*/

        private int Minimax(byte[] ngrid, int depth = 0)
        {
            if (depth == 0)
            {
                return Minimax(new byte[] { grid[0], grid[1], grid[2], 
                                            grid[3], grid[4], grid[5], 
                                            grid[6], grid[7], grid[8] },
                                            depth + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                int status = GameStatus(ngrid);
                if (status == PLAYER_WON) return -1;
                else if (status == COMPUTER_WON) return 1;
                else if (status == DRAW) return 0;
                int i;
                int score = 0;

                List<Carrier> carry = new List<Carrier>();

                for (i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ngrid[i] == 0)
                    {
                        byte[] board = new byte[] { 
                            ngrid[0], ngrid[1], ngrid[2], 
                            ngrid[3], ngrid[4], ngrid[5], 
                            ngrid[6], ngrid[7], ngrid[8]
                        };

                        board[i] = (depth % 2 == 0) ? (byte)PLAYER : (byte)COMPUTER;
                        score += Minimax(board, depth + 1);

                        if (depth == 1)
                        {
                            Carrier c = new Carrier();
                            c.offset = i;
                            c.score = score;
                            carry.Add(c);
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (depth == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("");
                }

                return score;

            }


        }

        private void ComputersTurn()
        {
            turn = COMPUTER;
            turns++;
            int status = GameStatus(grid);

            switch (status)
            {
                case GAME:
                    int offset = Minimax(grid);
                    grid[offset] = COMPUTER;                    
                    turn = PLAYER;
                    UpdateBoard();
                    break;                
            }

            switch (GameStatus(grid))
            {
                case PLAYER_WON:
                    turn = COMPUTER;
                    MessageBox.Show("You win!");
                    break;

                case COMPUTER_WON:
                    turn = COMPUTER;
                    MessageBox.Show("You lost!");
                    break;

                case DRAW:
                    turn = COMPUTER;
                    MessageBox.Show("DRAW!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateBoard()
        {
            int n = 0;
            grid0.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ( (grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark) ) : "";
            n++;
            grid1.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid2.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid3.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid4.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid5.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid6.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid7.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
            grid8.Text = (grid[n] != 0) ? ((grid[n] == PLAYER ? player_mark : computer_mark)) : "";
            n++;
        }

        private int GameStatus(byte[] pgrid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (pgrid[i * 3] == pgrid[i * 3 + 1] && pgrid[i * 3] == pgrid[i * 3 + 2] && pgrid[i * 3] != 0)
                    return SelectWinner(pgrid[i * 3]);
                if (pgrid[i] == pgrid[i + 3] && pgrid[i] == pgrid[i + 6] && pgrid[i] != 0)
                    return SelectWinner(pgrid[i]);
            }

            if (pgrid[0] == pgrid[4] && pgrid[0] == pgrid[8] && pgrid[0] != 0)
                return SelectWinner(pgrid[0]);
            if (pgrid[2] == pgrid[4] && pgrid[2] == pgrid[6] && pgrid[2] != 0)
                return SelectWinner(pgrid[2]);

            if (turns == 4)
                return DRAW;

            return GAME;

        }

        private int SelectWinner(byte item)
        {
            if (item == PLAYER)
                return PLAYER_WON;
            else if (item == COMPUTER)
                return COMPUTER_WON;

            throw new Exception("SELECTION ERROR");
        }

        private void grid0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;

            grid[0] = PLAYER;
            grid0.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[1] = PLAYER;
            grid1.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[2] = PLAYER;
            grid2.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[3] = PLAYER;
            grid3.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[4] = PLAYER;
            grid4.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[5] = PLAYER;
            grid5.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[6] = PLAYER;
            grid6.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[7] = PLAYER;
            grid7.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }

        private void grid8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turn == COMPUTER)
                return;
            grid[8] = PLAYER;
            grid8.Text = player_mark;
            ComputersTurn();
        }
    }

    class Carrier
    {
        public int score;
        public int offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing that jumps out at me is this piece:

```
score += Minimax(...
```

I think you'll want your minimax to select the move with the best score and return that score, not the sum of the scores for all possible moves from that position.